# Scroll Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs horizontally

Tags: html, css, tabs, bootstrap-4

I am using the new Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs functionality to create tabs. I'm trying to make all the tabs stay in one horizontal line that can be scrolled.

I tried some JavaScript plugins but none of it seem to work for Bootstrap 4.

This is my code so far. If anyone can add a JavaScript function to remove the scrollbar at the button, I'd be very grateful.

I'm just a newbie in JS. Please help out

```css
.nav-tabs {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}

.nav-tabs>a {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-row">
      <nav class="tabbable">
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
      <div class="tab-content pt-2" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Contact</div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Future readers looking for responsive scrolling (not scrollbar) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447884/171456 OR https://stackoverflow.com/a/53500150/171456

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here, You have add your code inside `.row`. but, would be used `.row`. when your are use `col` grid system. Here, You can use following Html structural & css for horizontal scrolled.

```css
.tabbable .nav-tabs {
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.tabbable .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
          <nav class="tabbable">
            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">My Profile</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="tab-content pt-2" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Contact</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi my friend, I tried your solution but I don`t know what the problem to me. would you please help  me too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009055/nav-pills-bootstrap-not-horizontal-scrolling

Comment: dear friend. thank you. just what i need.