# How to make nav-tabs scroll horizontally in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've found lot of examples for other bootstrap versions online but i can't find nothing to make nav-tabs scroll horizontally in bootstrap 3...

i've tryed lot of css by setting the container of nav to block and other stuff but nothing..

Here is my nav-tabs:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item active" role="presentation"><a href="#001" aria-controls="001" role="tab">EDENRED</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#002" aria-controls="002" role="tab">DAY</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#003" aria-controls="003" role="tab">SODEXO</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#004" aria-controls="004" role="tab">GRUPPO PELLEGRINI</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#005" aria-controls="005" role="tab">COMPASS GROUP - RISTOMAT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#006" aria-controls="006" role="tab">QUI</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#007" aria-controls="007" role="tab">CIR BLUTICKET</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#008" aria-controls="008" role="tab">JAKALA</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#009" aria-controls="009" role="tab">MIG FOR YOU</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#010" aria-controls="010" role="tab">SODEXO GIFT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How could i make it scroll horizontally instead of going in newline when the items doesn't fit the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    height: 100%;
}

/** Optionally if you don't want word wrap **/
.nav-tabs > li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.headerContainer {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<div class="headerContainer">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item active" role="presentation"><a href="#001" aria-controls="001" role="tab">EDENRED</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#002" aria-controls="002" role="tab">DAY</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#003" aria-controls="003" role="tab">SODEXO</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#004" aria-controls="004" role="tab">GRUPPO PELLEGRINI</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#005" aria-controls="005" role="tab">COMPASS GROUP - RISTOMAT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#006" aria-controls="006" role="tab">QUI</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#007" aria-controls="007" role="tab">CIR BLUTICKET</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#008" aria-controls="008" role="tab">JAKALA</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#009" aria-controls="009" role="tab">MIG FOR YOU</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#010" aria-controls="010" role="tab">SODEXO GIFT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav></div>
```

Comment: that will make whole html to scroll horizontally while i would scroll only the nav-tabs like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960182/scroll-bootstrap-4-nav-tabs-horizontally (but it works only in Bootstrap 4)

Comment: The `html { width: fit-content; }` is just because the SO snippet doesn't have an element above it. But if you have a wrapper, like a header, you could apply the width on that element.

Comment: I've replaced the `html` css with a container.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to add a scroll on the X axis, you just need to add to your style.css file this:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

But, in my oppinion, this is an very unusual thing to do.

Comment: it will be used only in a touchscreen machine so it will be nicer to scroll it horizontally