# column tab scroll horizontal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a row of tabs for my website, but when there are many tabs, the "Knowledgebase" tab drops to the bottom, causing a vertical scrollbar to appear. I want to make the row of tabs scroll horizontally when there are many tabs, so that all the tabs remain visible and the "Knowledgebase" tab doesn't drop to the bottom.

I tried using overflow: scroll in the CSS, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. How can I make the tab row scroll horizontally when needed, ensuring all tabs are visible and the "Knowledgebase" tab remains in its original position?

This is the website view
[image: [this is the website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grmf5.png)]

here is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                <div data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" tabindex="0" style="height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; position: relative;">
                    <div class="tab-content border">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link active" id="tab-ticket" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ticket" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="ticket" aria-selected="true">Ticket</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Customer</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="ticket" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-ticket">
                                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('admin/ticket/updateticket')}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>ID Ticket</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_ticket" id="id_ticket" disabled>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Subject</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="project" id="id_project">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
                                                    @if ($errors->has('subject'))
                                                        <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('subject') }}</span>
                                                    @endif
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="source" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"> <strong>Source</strong><sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                                    <select name="source" id="source" class="form-control show-tick ms select2"
                                                    data-placeholder="Select">
                                                    <option>Select</option>
                                                    {{--<option value="{{$project->id}}" selected>{{$project->project_name}}</option> --}}
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Agent</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="agent" id="agent" readonly>
                                                    @if ($errors->has('subject'))
                                                        <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('agent') }}</span>
                                                    @endif
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="source" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><strong>Priority</strong><sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                                    <select name="priority" id="priority" class="form-control show-tick ms select2" data-placeholder="Select">
                                                        <option></option>
                                                        {{-- @foreach ($sources as $item)
                                                            <option value="{{$item->skill_name}}">{{$item->skill_name}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach --}}
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Status</strong></label>
                                                <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control show-tick ms select2"
                                                    data-placeholder="Select">
                                                    <option></option>
                                                    {{-- @foreach($master_statuss as $row)
                                                    <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->status_name}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach --}}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Project</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_project" id="project" readonly>
                                                    @if ($errors->has('subject'))
                                                        <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('project') }}</span>
                                                    @endif
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Tags</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="Type 1 or 2 character">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                                <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Description</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description">
                                                    @if ($errors->has('description'))
                                                        <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('description') }}</span>
                                                    @endif
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer text-end">
                                            <div class="d-flex">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-1 flex-grow-1" type="submit">Edit New Ticket</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                                <form action="{{url('admin/updatecust')}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="title" class="form-label">Title <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title1" placeholder="Mr. or Ms." required>
                                                @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('title') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Name</strong></label>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_customer" id="id_customer_choose">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_customer" id="name">
                                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="TextInput" class="form-label"><strong>Email</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="phone_no" class="form-label"><strong>Phone No</strong> <sup class="text-danger">*</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_no" id="phone1">
                                                @if ($errors->has('phone_no'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('phone_no') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="mobile_phone" class="form-label"><strong>Mobile Phone</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone11">
                                                @if ($errors->has('mobile_phone'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('mobile_phone') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="address" class="form-label"><strong>Address</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address1">
                                                @if ($errors->has('address'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('address') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="tags" class="form-label"><strong>Tags</strong> <sup class="text-danger">*</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tags" id="tags1" data-role="tagsinput" required>
                                                @if ($errors->has('tags'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('tags') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 mb-1">
                                            <label for="wa" class="form-label"><strong>WhatsApp</strong></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wa" id="wa1">
                                                @if ($errors->has('wa'))
                                                    <span class="text-danger">* {{ $errors->first('wa') }}</span>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer text-end">
                                            <div class="d-flex">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-1 flex-grow-1" type="submit">Create</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="knowledge" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="knowledge-tab">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h6 class="text-center"><strong>Knowledge Base</strong></h6>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_search_knowledge" onkeyup="searchKnowledge()" placeholder="Search Knowledge Title">
                                        <hr>
                                        <div data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" tabindex="0" style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; position: relative;">
                                            <table id="table_knowledge_base" class="table table-hover table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                                                <thead style="display:none;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Knowledge Base</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    @if(!count($knowledge_bases))
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="">
                                                                <div class="card overflow-visible">
                                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                                                                            <div class="col ml-n2">
                                                                                <strong>No Data</strong>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    @else
                                                        @foreach($knowledge_bases as $kb_file)
                                                            @foreach ($kb_folders as $kb_folder)
                                                                @if(($kb_file->id_kb_folder === $kb_folder->id) && ($kb_file->active === 'yes'))
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{ $kb_file->id }}" data-whatever="@mdo" style="cursor: pointer">
                                                                                <div class="card overflow-visible justify-content-center" style="height: 50px;">
                                                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                                                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                                                                                            <div class="col ml-n2">
                                                                                                <strong>{{ $kb_file->title }}</strong>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            {{-- <div class="col-auto">
                                                                                                <div class="avatar rounded no-thumbnail">
                                                                                                    @if ($kb_file->file != null)
                                                                                                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg"></i>
                                                                                                    @elseif($kb_file->file == null)
                                                                                                        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg"></i>
                                                                                                    @endif
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div> --}}
                                                                                            {{-- <div class="col-auto">
                                                                                                <span class="text-muted d-flex small">Jenis File</span>
                                                                                                <span class="text-muted d-flex small">Ukuran File</span>
                                                                                            </div> --}}
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                @endif
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @endif
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960182/scroll-bootstrap-4-nav-tabs-horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have used 'nowrap' so it will keep the overflow another way is fixed width hope it works for you

```css
#myTab{
overflow-x:auto;
flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link active" id="tab-ticket" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ticket" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="ticket" aria-selected="true">Ticket</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Customer</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                             <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="knowledge-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#knowledge" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="knowledge" aria-selected="false">Knowledge</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the row of tabs scroll horizontally when there are many tabs, you can apply the following CSS changes:

1. Remove the `data-spy="scroll"` attribute and the inline style with `overflow-y: scroll` from the container holding the tab list (`<div class="col-lg-3">`);
2. Add a new CSS class to the tab list container to control the horizontal scrolling behavior (`tab-list-container` in this example);
3. Apply the necessary CSS styles to enable horizontal scrolling and ensure all tabs remain visible.

Here's the updated HTML and CSS code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
 <div class="tab-list-container">
  <div class="tab-content border">
   <!-- Tab content and other elements -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
    
.tab-list-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
    
/* Optional */
.tab-list-container .tab-content {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
    
/* Optional */
.tab-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
    
.tab-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

With these changes, the tab row should now scroll horizontally when there are many tabs, and all the tabs, including the "Knowledgebase" tab, should remain visible. The `tab-list-container` class enables horizontal scrolling with `overflow-x: auto`, and `white-space: nowrap` ensures the tabs stay in a single line. The optional CSS styles for the scrollbar are just for visual customization and can be adjusted as per your preference.